# Google api key usage limit and key/app

Tags: android

I recently put together with Google Maps Android API v2 and Google Maps API v3.
Bascially it use web v3 to return xml direction to parsing it to android and draw the lines.

I have got question regards to Google Maps API v3 usage limit.

1. Is it possible to increase the request limit without paying the extra cost when over the 2.5k requests?
2. Correct me if I am wrong about this. Says if 250 people downloaded the app, and each person made 10 requests and made request in total over 2.5k on the same day.  Will the next request crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google calculates an average of the last xxx (90?) days. In their TOC you can find this info. Here the link in german. Change url for your language:   [> TOC <](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=de#usagelimits)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  But that doesn't really answer the two Q's above though. I am still in searching for specific answers here.

Comment: First at all: Its not 2.5K! Its 25K! Answer for question1 => NOWAY. Answer for question2 Read the tocs again. The answer is inside. My interpretation is, that request 25001 will work. But im sure, that it will not work after 90 days. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

*This question is old, but if anyone is searching for an answer:*

If you omit the `key` parameter in your directions requests, the per-IP limits kick in. That is, each device running your app gets **2500 requests per day.**

**This will enforce per-key limits:**

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Sharjah&destination=Dubai&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>`

**while this will enforce per-IP limits:**

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Sharjah&destination=Dubai`

You need the second one.